# How does a fish not live when there is still water in the acquarium?

Tags: water, atoms, biophysics, molecules

Can an acquarium still contain water but no oxygen (which seems impossible since water exists means oxygen exists!) for the fish to live on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie, I agree that it might be off-topic for this forum, but I don't agree that it is not a question about physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish "breathe" the oxygen gas that is dissolved in the water. They don't use a chemical reaction to decompose the water molecules into hydrogen and oxygen.

That is why you have to bubble air through the water in an aquarium, to replace the oxygen that is removed by the fish.

In nature, air is more easily dissolved through the surface of the water, because currents in the water and wind over the surface "stirs" the water and distributes the dissolved oxygen through it. That doesn't happen in an aquarium tank where there are no natural water currents or air flows.

Even in nature, fish can die through lack of oxygen in some situations - for example if other organisms in the water, such as algae, reproduce too fast and use up the dissolved oxygen faster than it can be replaced.

Comment: Might be worth noting that some fish (such as those in the carp family) can live in water with relative low dissolved $O_2$, which is why goldfish can be kept in simple bowls. Enough oxygen diffuses in through the exposed surface for the minimal needs of the animal.